# update SQLite database android

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello i have MySQLite database in my android project and Im trying to update one of the coloume and it doesn't work
my code:
db source:

```
 public void updateToken(int id, int tokens)
{
    List<User> users = getAllUsers();
    dbHelper.updateToken(database, id, users.get(id).getUsername(),users.get(id).getPassword(), 10);
}
```

SQLite helper:

```
epublic void updateToken(SQLiteDatabase db,int id, String username,String password,int newToken) {


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
    cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, password);
    cv.put(COLUMN_TOKENS, newToken);
    db.update(TABLE_USERS,cv,"_id "+"="+id,null);


}
```

calling the method :

```
dataSource.updateToken(userID,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

As see here [SQLiteDatabase.update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) takes `whereArgs` as last parameter.

So,instead of passing last param `null` in `update` method pass `id` value according to which want to update row value like:

```
 String[] whereArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(id)};
 db.update(TABLE_USERS,cv,"_id=?",whereArgs);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work i get no exceptions or crashes it just not updating

Comment: @SurBt: try to attach debugger and breakpoint in application and may be not sure if get any effect try  to use `id` instead of `_id`

Comment: down-voters please leave comment why down-vote answer to improve it.Thanks